# Node.js render 404 page when page doesn't exist with params

Tags: node.js, parameters, http-status-code-404

I am hoping someone can help me, I've looked at some possible solutions but I just don't know where I am going wrong! I am learning so please forgive me if this is something simple.

So the following code works rendering the index.ejs file when going to the home route, and fine when going to an existing page.

```
app.get(`/`, function (req, res) {
    res.render(`index`);
});

app.get(`/:page`, function (req, res) {
    const page = req.params.page;
    res.render(`${page}`);
});
```

For example, if I type **/main** then the main.ejs file is rendered ok.

If I type **/asdkjbasfijbs** (basically a non-existent page) then I want it to render a 404 page that I already have in the 'views' folder but at the moment it says

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "asdkjbasfijbs" in views directory "/views"
```

Here's my full code:

```
const express = require(`express`);
const https = require(`https`);
const ejs = require(`ejs`);
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.set(`view engine`, `ejs`);
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(`public`));

app.get(`/`, function (req, res) {
    res.render(`index`);
});

app.get(`/:page`, function (req, res) {
    const page = req.params.page;
    res.render(`${page}`);
});

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

I've tried adding the following at the end of my routes:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
res.status(404).send(`Not Found`);
});
```

and

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
res.status(404).render(`404`);
});
```

and

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
const err = new httpError(404)
return next(err);
});
```

Comment: Could You provide link to the repo  Please ?

Comment: Hi there. I've just uploaded them here: https://github.com/010010100110000101111001/params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://expressjs.com/de/api.html#res.render) you should be able to provide a callback, which receives an `err` or the rendered `html`

If there is an error send a 404 (or check what the error is and send the respective status code). If there is no error, return the rendered html.

```
res.render(page, (err, html) => {
  if (err) return res.sendStatus(404);
  res.type('html').send(html);
})
```

Or you can add a default [error handler](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) to your routes

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  //check what error happened here ... 
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
})
```

Comment: Many thanks, the default error handler worked.